# Can you run a script every time /bin/sh is invoked?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

With bash, you can set your ~/.bashrc file to run something every time a new bash shell is created. Is it possible to do the same thing with /bin/sh? (This is on Debian, by the way).

For now, I just want to echo 'I am sh' when /bin/sh is invoked. It's easy to do in bash ("echo 'I am bash'" placed at the top of the file).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When starting a login shell of `dash`, which is `/bin/sh` on debian-like systems, it will read `~/.profile`.  If you also want a configuration file read for interactive non-login shells, add the following line to your `~/.profile` file:

```
ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV
```

Then, with the variable `ENV` appearing in the environment, the file `$HOME/.shinit` will be sourced with every new interactive (dash) shell.

You may change the file name specified by `ENV` to any file name you prefer.

To assure a dash login shell has added `ENV` to the environment, you may need to logout and log back in, or possibly reboot, depending on your system setup.

#### Documentation

This is documented in `man dash`:

> A login shell first reads
>        commands from the files /etc/profile and .profile if they exist.  If the environment variable ENV
>        is set on entry to an interactive shell, or is set in the .profile of a login shell, the shell
>        next reads commands from the file named in ENV.  Therefore, a user should place commands that are
>        to be executed only at login time in the .profile file, and commands that are executed for every
>        interactive shell inside the ENV file.

#### Example

Suppose that we have files set up like:

```
$ echo "ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV" >>~/.profile
$ cat .shinit
echo FOUND ME
```

Since I just added the `ENV` line to the `~/.profile` file, `ENV` is not yet in the environment.  If we run `dash`:

```
$ dash
$
```

Nothing happened because this is a non-login shell and `ENV` is not yet in the environment.

If we start a login shell, `ENV` is placed in the environment and `~/.shinit` is run:

```
$ dash -l
FOUND ME
```

If, as a child of that shell, we run an interactive non-login shell, then `~/.shinit` will be run because the parent shell created the `ENV` variable:

```
$ dash
FOUND ME
```

The environment created by the login shell above only affects its children.  To assure that all interactive `dash` shells have `ENV` in their environment may, as mentioned above, require logging out and back in, or a reboot.